# Yii2, gridview can not show some html tags inside cells

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using `GridView` widget for displaying data in my Yii2 application. The gridview can not render some of html tags, such as `<input>` or `<button>`!.

here is part of my code:

```
[
     "label" => "Action",
     "format" => 'html',
     "value" => function($data){
           return '<input type="button" value="Action" />';
      }
]
```

This renders **nothing** inside `<td>`, just empty `<td></td>` !!

What's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "html" formatter is piped through HtmlPurifier to clean it up.

If you want it to pass through without any filtering then use the format "raw" instead of "html"